# Аутентификация пользователя в Laravel из сторонней базы с использованием нескольких таблиц

Tags: база-данных, laravel, laravel-5.8

У меня есть 2 базы: одна от Laravel, другая от XenForo 2 (на самом деле, вторая не важно от чего, но для конкретности пусть будет так). На Laravel регистрация проходить не должна, а проходит только на форуме для того, чтобы уменьшить дублирование данных и исключить рассинхрон, если он по каким-то причинам произойдёт.

В XF есть 2 таблицы: **xf_users** - хранит основную информацию о пользователе, и **xf_user_authenticate** - хранит сериализованную строку-массив с хешем пароля.

Необходимо проводить аутентификацию через эти 2 таблицы. Пользователь ввёл логин/пароль правильно - вошёл в Laravel.
**Как это можно реализовать в Laravel?**

К сторонней БД подключиться просто: вручную соединение прописать в модели User прописать так:

```
protected $connection = 'forum';
protected $table = 'xf_users';
public $timestamps = false;
```

Создал ещё модель Password для получения паролей с таблицы xf_user_authenticate с методом для получения хеша пароля:

```
class Password extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['data'];
    protected $connection = 'forum';
    protected $table = 'xf_user_authenticate';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public static function getPassHash($uid){
        $data = Password::firstWhere('user_id', '=', $uid)->get();
        return unserialize($data->data)['hash'];
    }
}
```

Дальше, как я понял, нужно сделать кастомный guard и provider, и вот тут я уже не могу понять, что делать дальше...

---

**UPD**: Ответы ниже в принципе верны, и они дествительно помогут при очень сложной "макаронной" аутентификации, но мне всё же не хватило понимания написанного после прочтения документации.

Однако, во время того, как я пытался решить задачу, пришло банальное и простое решение - переопределить отдаваемый моделью пароль. И тогда проблема сразу же решается. Изначально я мыслил в правильном направлении, но просто не хватило понимания самого фреймворка.
Модель User должна выглядеть следующим образом (в частности для получения данных и аутентификации пользователей из XF):

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'user_state']; //Не обязательно, если не нужно записывать пользователей, а только брать
    protected $connection = 'forum';
    protected $table = 'xf_user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getAuthPassword(){
        $password = Password::where('user_id', '=', $this->user_id)->select('data')->first();
        return unserialize($password->data)['hash'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополню ответ @jhaoda - ответ кроется прямо в документации, а именно автору нужно просто реализовать свой кастомный UserProvider, в документации шикарный пример:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\Auth\JwtGuard;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::extend('jwt', function ($app, $name, array $config) {
            // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard...

            return new JwtGuard(Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider']));
        });
    }
}
```

Также вопрос решается при помощи [Closure Request Guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#closure-request-guards), пример по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ, как обычно, есть в документации — [Adding Custom User Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: День добрый. Было бы хорошо, если бы вы в ответ основные моменты из статьи по ссылке перенесли ^_^